# CSS background image barely visible in div

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

Working on a page for a gym (http://purcraft.com/madeinla/the-gym/) and there's supposed to be a background image of the gym on this page. Instead, there's only a slight portion of the image in this div. The rest of black but I've been playing around with it inspector and I can't even locate a background color at all for the div's after this area. So why would I be getting this? Here's my CSS:

```
body.page-id-30 .site-content { background-image: url(images/bkg-gym.jpg); background-size: cover; }
body.page-id-30 .copy-gym { position: absolute; left: 250px; bottom: 38px; width: 530px; font-family: 'texgyreheroscnregular', sans-serif;  text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with removing the position:absolute; attribute from the div of class "copy-gym".
I don't know how exactly you'd like the page to look like but I'd suggest you to try using a ready css layout because it seems that you use too much divs for a very simple layout.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/

There for example you can find sample layouts for use.